# Inference variabe T has incompatible bounds while using .collect(toList())

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

The task was:

> Modify bonuses for all workers whose name starts with a letter from the second half of the alphabet.

```
class Worker that extends Employee
{
    public Worker(String name, int yOfEmp, int salary, Manager boss){
        super(name, yOfEmp, salary,boss);
        boss.addEmployee(this);
    }

    public float getBonus(Employee emp){
        Random rand = new Random();
        float proc = rand.nextFloat();
        return emp.getSalary() * proc;
    }
    public float setBonus(Employee e, float proc){
        float newProc = proc;
        return e.getSalary() * proc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

---

```
class RegWorker extends Worker
{
}
```

---

```
class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] str) {
    Manager bill = new Manager("Bill", 2010, 2549, null);
    Manager steven = new Manager("Steven", 2011, 2100, bill);
    Trainer jerry = new Trainer("Jerry", 2014, 800, steven);
    RegWorker john = new RegWorker("John", 2010, 1000, bill);
    RegWorker kate = new RegWorker("Kate", 2011, 1000, bill);
    RegWorker sam = new RegWorker("Sam", 2013, 1200, steven);

    final List<Worker> workers = Arrays.asList(jerry, john, kate, sam);

    System.out.println("Modify bonuses for all regular workers:");
    RegWorker reg = null;

    List<RegWorker> regWorkers = workers
                .stream()
                .filter(w -> w.getClass() == reg.getClass())
                .filter(w -> w.getName().charAt(0) < 'O')
                .map(w -> w.setBonus(w, w.getBonus(w)+3))
                .collect(toList());
    }
```

---

**I've got this**
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w7i9.png)

> reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
>   equality constraints: RegWorker
>   lower bounds: Float

Comment: There's too much code and it is also quite weird: `reg.getClass()` is guaranteed to fail with `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 3):

When you're doing `map`, you replace stream objects with mapper function return value which is return value of `setBonus`, which is float. So after the `map` step you have not `Stream<RegWorker>`, but `Stream<Float>` which should be collected into `List<Float>`.

It seems that you want to use `peek` instead of `map`. Also you will need to cast stream elements to `RegWorker` class as your original stream is `Stream<Worker>`. Finally note that your code has another problem which will appear in runtime: `reg.getClass()` will throw `NullPointerException` as `reg` is null. Probably you just need `.filter(w -> w instanceof RegWorker)`:

```
List<RegWorker> regWorkers = workers
            .stream()
            .filter(w -> w instanceof RegWorker)
            .filter(w -> w.getName().charAt(0) < 'O')
            .map(w -> (RegWorker)w)
            .peek(w -> w.setBonus(w, w.getBonus(w)+3))
            .collect(toList());
```

Comment: And why not combine the two filters on the same line.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard, that's the matter of taste.

Comment: @TagirValeev Doesn't it add time complexity ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard, you'll never know until you measure. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24054773/4856258).

Comment: Thanks for the link, not sure why but I tought I had seem somewhere that it added time complexity and never verified myself.

Comment: It’s more likely that moving `.filter(w -> w.getName().charAt(0) < 'O')` to the beginning of the chain improves performance as a character comparison is cheaper than `instanceof` and bringing the steps `.filter(w -> w instanceof RegWorker)` and `.map(w -> (RegWorker)w)` closer together raises the chance of them getting fused together by HotSpot. However, that’s all speculative and only about tendencies. It’s also very likely that the entire operation gets optimized as a single code block and then all differences are negligible.