# how to handle Optional Object in java streams api?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am doing simple test.

```
@Test
    public void whenFilterEmployees_thenGetFilteredEmployees(){
        Integer[] empIds = {1,2,3};
        List<Optional<Employee>> employees = Stream.of(empIds)
                .map(employeeRepository::findById)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Employee> employeeList = employees
                .stream().filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .filter(e->e !=null)
                .filter(e->e.getSalary()>200000)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(arrayOfEmps[2]), employeeList);


    }
```

and my employee table contains data:

```
1   Jeff Bezos  100000
2   Bill Gates  200000
3   Mark Zuckerberg 300000
```

the current test runs successfully.

as you can see i have prepared two list of employees i.e employees and employeeList

i did so because `findById` method returns Optional. how can i use the streams api so that i can get list of employees simply as

```
List<Employee> employeeList= ....
```

Comment: There is no reason to split both streams. Just use one, request the DB, filter if present, apply other filters, then collect to list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Java 8's Optional with Stream::flatMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725537/using-java-8s-optional-with-streamflatmap)

Comment: @LuisG. Not a duplicate as the question is not asking about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just merge the two stream pipelines i.e.

```
List<Employee> employees = Stream.of(empIds)
                                 .map(employeeRepository::findById)
                                 .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                                 .map(Optional::get)
                               //.filter(e->e !=null) not needed as it's redundant
                                 .filter(e->e.getSalary()>200000)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: does it work ? because i get non-static method cannot be referenced from static context on .filter(Optional::isPresent)

Comment: @sagarlimbu on my phone atm but I don’t see a reason why it shouldn’t compile. Probably a type inference issue... what IDE are you using?

Comment: sorry i didn't see your answer properly. i actually used filter(Optional::get) instead of .map(Optional::get).

Answer (score 4):

We can write the code shorter using `Optional.stream` (requires Java 9+):

```
List<Employee> employees = Stream.of(empIds)
        .flatMap(id -> employeeRepository.findById(id).stream())
        .filter(e -> e.getSalary() > 200000)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream()) `Optional.stream`

> returns a sequential `Stream` containing only that value, otherwise
>   returns an empty `Stream`.

Thus we can go on with the `filter` operation at once.

Comment: @Holger Added this to my answer. Thx.

Comment: Just read your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048056/determine-if-a-list-composed-of-anagram-elements-in-java-8/53062631#comment93022997_53048444) about "method reference overuse" :). As I wrote how to get the code shorter, it's only consistent to follow your suggestion. Updated my answer.

Comment: Well, I wouldn’t consider two method references “overuse”. And it’s easier to overlook when `map` and `flatMap` steps can be merged. It’s a different beast with four subsequent `map` steps…

Comment: Wouldn't you still need a check for null, since op checks for null?

Comment: @matt Do you refer to `filter(e->e !=null)` in OP's code? The filtering in my answer's code takes place afer `Optional.stream()`has been flat mapped. Thus the case  `e == null` cannot occour.

Comment: So OP doesn't need it either then, since they call it after `.map(Optional::get)`

Comment: Correct. The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent()) for `Optional.isPresent` says: "If a value is present, returns true, otherwise false." So if the `Optional` is empty, the filter will not be passed. But if it's passed, then it's safe to call `Optional.get` and the [value returned is not null](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get()).