# Checking if single date does not colliding with the date list

Tags: java, datetime, functional-programming, java-stream

Let's say that we have a `TrainingDate` class like below:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
class TrainingDate {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private LocalDateTime startDate;

  private LocalDateTime endDate;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "trainingDate")
  private Training training;

}
```

I want to create a method that will check if the proposed date of training will not collide with the time table of the trainer. The method looks like:

```
private boolean isTrainingDateNotCollidingWithTrainerSchedule(List<Training> trainerTrainings,
      TrainingDate potentialTrainingDate) {

    List<TrainingDate> trainingList = trainerTrainings
        .stream()
        .map(Training::getTrainingDate)
        .filter(
            trainingDate -> trainingDate.startDate.isAfter(potentialTrainingDate.endDate) &&
                trainingDate.endDate.isBefore(potentialTrainingDate.startDate))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (trainingList.size() > 1) {
      throw exception here 
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Seemingly it's working fine but for me, it's not so gentle way to reach a goal. Here comes the question, is it possible to refactor the above solution and make it a little more clear. I know that I can split this `filter` declaration but this post [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054773/java-8-streams-multiple-filters-vs-complex-condition) suggests that this is not a good choice if we will take a final performance into consideration. I will be grateful for the suggestion on how to check if `start date` and `end date` will not collide with the trainer timetable by improving clearness of the current solution.

Comment: That condition looks wrong, how can one period both start after another period has ended and end before the other period has started? Off topic but TrainingDate is a strange name for something that has a start and an end date, maybe it would be better to use something like period, interval or schedule.

Comment: What does this method return `getTrainingDate` and is this property inside of `TrainingDate` or `Training` ?

Comment: a simple refactoring would be to move the comparison inside a method called `overlap(LocalDateTime otherstart, LocalDateTime otherend)` inside `TrainingDate` class. And then as Joakim mentioned, you have to fix the condition to: `(startDate.isBefore(otherStart) && endDate.isAfter(otherStart)) || (startDate.isBefore(otherEnd) && endDate.isAfter(otherEnd));`

Answer (score 0):

You can return directly a result from stream

```
private boolean isTrainingDateNotCollidingWithTrainerSchedule(List<Training> trainerTrainings,TrainingDate potentialTrainingDate) {

     return trainerTrainings.stream().noneMatch(trainingDate -> trainingDate.startDate.isAfter(potentialTrainingDate.endDate) &&
            trainingDate.endDate.isBefore(potentialTrainingDate.startDate));
}
```