Java Stream API memory consumption of multiple .filter() in chain
Have a question regarding .filter (or any other non-terminal) methods in Stream API chain (code in the block below is just for example):
var s1 = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
var intemidiate1 = s1.filter(i -> i % 2 == 0);
var intemidiate2 = intemidiate1.filter(i -> i < 10);
var intemidiate3 = intemidiate2.filter(i -> i < 1);
var res = intemidiate3.toList();

By hashcodes of each non-terminal operation I clearly see that Stream API creates new object of Stream each time, so does it makes sense to merge filter methods as much as possible (1 instead of ten) and give up with readability in favor of memory consumption/ performance?

I guess that such micro-optimizations are a waste of time, and will likely hardly have any benefit, but you'd have to profile it to be sure.

Are you asking about s1.filter(1).filter(2).filter(3) versus s1.filter(1.2.3)? Have you referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054773/java-8-streams-multiple-filters-vs-complex-condition ?

I don’t see how .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).filter(i -> i < 1) is more readable than .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0 && i < 1), not to speak of your variant with all these additional local variables with meaningless names.
